# Employee First IN & Last OUT Swipe - SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query in SQL Server 2012 to calculate time difference between First IN & Last OUT swipes for each employee(for normal day shift and night shift) in the company.Below is the sample data I have for the query.

```
Create table #TempData  (EmpName nvarchar(50),EventDateTime DateTime, TrnName nvarchar(20),TrnCode int)

Insert Into #TempData Values
('User1','2015-08-04 09:10:53','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-04 10:43:52','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-04 11:13:23','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-04 13:32:29','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-05 09:46:19','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-05 10:22:28','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-06 18:47:02','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-06 19:29:02','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-06 21:05:26','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-18 11:54:42','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-18 19:19:02','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-18 20:15:01','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-18 20:57:49','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-19 12:10:48','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-20 11:57:04','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-20 20:57:19','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-24 18:14:26','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-25 02:28:31','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-28 17:14:05','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-29 04:50:28','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-09-03 17:40:53','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-09-04 02:42:57','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-09-04 18:27:25','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-09-04 18:27:29','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-09-05 02:32:31','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-09-07 10:58:24','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-09-07 14:04:54','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-09-07 17:55:52','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-09-08 17:51:20','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-09-09 02:25:20','Exit','1')
```

And below is the query I am using.

```
 ;with cte as
(
    select 
    ROW_NUMBER() over(order by EmpName,EventDateTime) rn,
    EmpName, EventDateTime,
    cast(EventDateTime as date) EventDate,
    TrnName,TrnCode
from #TempData 
)
,ctee
as
(
select 
 Ent.rn as Ent_Rn, Ent.EmpName as Ent_EmpName, 
 Ent.EventDate as Ent_EventDate, Ent.EventDateTime as Ent_EventDateTime, 
 Ex.rn as Ex_Rn,EX.EmpName as Ex_EmpName,
 Ex.EventDate as Ex_EventDate, Ex.EventDateTime as Ex_EventDateTime
from
(
select 
    * 
from cte 
where TrnName = 'Entrance'
) as Ent
full join
(
select 
    * 
from cte 
where TrnName = 'Exit'
) as Ex
on Ent.rn+1 = Ex.rn and Ent.EmpName = Ex.EmpName 
)
,cteee
as
(
select 
case when Ent_EmpName is null then  Ex_EmpName  
     else Ent_EmpName
end as EmpName, 
Ent_EventDateTime as LoginTime, 
case 
    when DATEDIFF(hour, cast(Ent_EventDateTime as datetime),   cast(Ex_EventDateTime as datetime))>14 then null
    else Ex_EventDateTime 
end as LogoutTime
from ctee
)

select
*,
DATEDIFF(second,LoginTime,LogoutTime) As Seconds
,TIMEFROMPARTS(((DATEDIFF(second,LoginTime,LogoutTime))%(3600*24)/3600), 
(((DATEDIFF(second,LoginTime,LogoutTime))%(3600*24)%3600)/60), 
(((DATEDIFF(second,LoginTime,LogoutTime))%(3600*24)%3600)%60),0, 0) AS   WorkTime
from cteee order by EmpName, LoginTime
```

Below is the current results I am getting from the above query.
[image]

However, this is not correct as this is reflecting the actual time between each IN & OUT and putting NULL for any missed IN/OUT. But the requirement is to get 1st IN and Last OUT for employee(normal & night shift timings), irrespective multiple IN's & OUT's between 1st IN & Last OUT. However, if any IN or OUT is missing or time difference between any IN and OUT is more 14 hours then mark it as NULL.
Below are the expected results.

[image]

Adding more data and results refelecting however the results are not correct, hence need to amend the query provided by NEER.

Data:

```
 ('User1','2015-07-20 11:07:29','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-20 11:08:09','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-20 21:13:27','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-21 12:07:03','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-21 21:04:02','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-22 11:48:06','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-22 13:37:15','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-22 13:57:58','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-22 20:59:22','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-23 12:38:41','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-23 17:33:43','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-23 18:09:13','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-23 21:03:13','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-24 11:51:03','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-24 14:19:41','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-24 14:36:55','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-24 20:51:06','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-27 12:10:54','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-27 17:45:36','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-27 18:36:24','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-27 19:16:21','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-27 20:01:12','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-27 21:04:47','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-28 11:24:09','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-28 21:05:32','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-29 12:03:09','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-29 18:36:07','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-29 19:25:16','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-29 21:00:28','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-30 11:58:43','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-30 13:09:18','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-30 13:25:02','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-30 21:00:20','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-31 12:11:36','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-31 19:46:47','Exit','1'),
 ('User1','2015-07-31 20:44:27','Entrance','0'),
 ('User1','2015-07-31 21:34:07','Exit','1')
```

Current Results:
[image]
This is the output I am getting with new data. Same results appear when I use table directly in the query.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still a bit lost, could you post what you'd want the final output to look like?

Comment: What about more then 1 `Exit` or `Entrance` in a row?

Comment: @JohnBustos i have added the results in the query.

Comment: @gofr1 i have data where more than 1 exit/entrance exists. So in case an Exit is there for any Entrance, we should ignore any partial swipes as far as we are getting First IN & Last OUT however if there is only one swipe per day, either IN or OUT then mark LoginInTime or LogOutTime as NULL respectively. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try as the below:

```
declare @TempData Table (EmpName nvarchar(50),EventDateTime DateTime, TrnName nvarchar(20),TrnCode int)

Insert Into @TempData Values
('User1','2015-08-04 09:10:53','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-04 10:43:52','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-04 11:13:23','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-04 13:32:29','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-05 09:46:19','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-05 10:22:28','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-06 18:47:02','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-06 19:29:02','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-06 21:05:26','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-18 11:54:42','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-18 19:19:02','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-18 20:15:01','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-18 20:57:49','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-19 12:10:48','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-20 11:57:04','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-20 20:57:19','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-24 18:14:26','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-25 02:28:31','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-08-28 17:14:05','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-08-29 04:50:28','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-09-03 17:40:53','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-09-04 02:42:57','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-09-04 18:27:25','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-09-04 18:27:29','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-09-05 02:32:31','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-09-07 10:58:24','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-09-07 14:04:54','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-09-07 17:55:52','Exit','1'),
('User1','2015-09-08 17:51:20','Entrance','0'),
('User1','2015-09-09 02:25:20','Exit','1'),
('B','2016-06-22 17:27:00','Exit','1'), 
('B','2016-06-22 17:42:01','Entrance','0'), 
('B','2016-06-22 21:27:59','Exit','1'), 
('B','2016-06-22 21:45:47','Exit','1'), 
('B','2016-06-22 21:56:15','Entrance','0'), 
('B','2016-06-23 00:42:44','Exit','1'), 
('B','2016-06-23 01:03:06','Entrance','0'), 
('B','2016-06-23 02:47:18','Exit','1')


;WITH CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(T.EventDateTime AS DATE)) AS RowId
    FROM
        @TempData T
), CTE2
AS
(
        SELECT 
            A.EmpName,
            A.EventDateTime,
            A.TrnName,
            A.TrnCode,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(B.RowId)) [Group]
        FROM 
            CTE1 A CROSS JOIN CTE1 B
        WHERE 
            ABS(DATEDIFF(HOUR, A.EventDateTime, B.EventDateTime)) BETWEEN 0 AND 14 -- Here 
        GROUP BY 
                A.EmpName,
                A.EventDateTime,
                A.TrnName,
                A.TrnCode
), CTE3
AS
(
    SELECT
        T.EmpName,      
        MIN(IIF(T.TrnCode = 0, T.EventDateTime, NULL)) InDate,
        MAX(IIF(T.TrnCode = 1, T.EventDateTime, NULL)) OutDate
    FROM
        CTE2 T
    GROUP BY
        T.EmpName,
        T.[Group]
), FinalTable
AS
(
    SELECT
        T.EmpName ,
        T.InDate,
        IIF(T.InDate > T.OutDate, NULL, T.OutDate) AS OutDate
    FROM CTE3 T 

    UNION

    SELECT
        T.EmpName ,
        IIF(T.InDate > T.OutDate, NULL, T.InDate) AS InDate,
        T.OutDate AS OutDate
    FROM CTE3 T 
)


SELECT
    F.EmpName ,
    F.InDate ,
    F.OutDate,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, F.InDate, F.OutDate) [Second],
    CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,F.InDate,F.OutDate),'1900-1-1'),8) WorkTime
FROM 
    FinalTable F
```

Result:

```
EmpName     InDate                      OutDate                     Second      WorkTime
----------- -----------------------     -----------------------     ----------- --------
User1       NULL                        2015-08-05 09:46:19.000     NULL        NULL
User1       2015-08-04 09:10:53.000     2015-08-04 13:32:29.000     15696       04:21:36
User1       2015-08-05 10:22:28.000     NULL                        NULL        NULL
User1       2015-08-06 19:29:02.000     2015-08-06 21:05:26.000     5784        01:36:24
User1       2015-08-18 11:54:42.000     2015-08-18 20:57:49.000     32587       09:03:07
User1       2015-08-19 12:10:48.000     NULL                        NULL        NULL
User1       2015-08-20 11:57:04.000     2015-08-20 20:57:19.000     32415       09:00:15
User1       2015-08-24 18:14:26.000     2015-08-25 02:28:31.000     29645       08:14:05
User1       2015-08-28 17:14:05.000     2015-08-29 04:50:28.000     41783       11:36:23
User1       2015-09-03 17:40:53.000     2015-09-04 02:42:57.000     32524       09:02:04
User1       2015-09-04 18:27:25.000     2015-09-05 02:32:31.000     29106       08:05:06
User1       2015-09-07 10:58:24.000     2015-09-07 17:55:52.000     25048       06:57:28
User1       2015-09-08 17:51:20.000     2015-09-09 02:25:20.000     30840       08:34:00
B           2016-06-22 17:42:01.000     2016-06-23 02:47:18.000     32717       09:05:17
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, i am currently testing this script for more than 100000 records and hoping to retrieve the required results in not more than 30 minutes :)

Comment: the query is not providing any results for data more than 100000 records. Could you please optimize your query to run quickly in SQL 2012?

Comment: @ankurjain Can you try as monthly?

Comment: it worked however i can find some issue in CTE2(having cross join of CT1) of the query as data is not reflecting correctly, please can you help to resolve that issue.

Comment: Show sample data please.

Comment: data is updated at the bottom of original question. I have added the screen shot of the results i am getting which is not correct. Please help to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below steps for calculating login,logout and working duration of each employee
1.1st create a temp table for data process from original table
2.later query from that temp table
3.drop that temp table

```
 Create table #Process_data (EmpName nvarchar(50),login_Time  DateTime,logout_Time DateTime)

go
insert into #process_data(EmpName,login_Time)
select EmpName,MIN(EventDateTime) as login_Time  from #TempData
where TrnCode =0
group by EmpName,CONVERT(date,EventDateTime)

go
update #process_data
set logout_Time=case when logout_Time is null
then ( SELECT 
MAX(EventDateTime)  FROM #TempData
where #TempData.EmpName= #process_data.EmpName
and CONVERT(date,#TempData.EventDateTime)=CONVERT(date,#process_data.login_Time)
 and EventDateTime>login_Time
 and TrnCode =1
  )
else logout_Time end 
 go

  select EmpName,login_Time,logout_time,  datediff(second,login_time,logout_time) as[second],datediff(second,login_time,logout_time)/3600.0 as workingTime
 from #process_data



             EmpName    login_Time              logout_time            second   workingTime
             User1      2015-08-04 09:10:53.000 2015-08-04 13:32:29.000 15696   4.360000
             User1      2015-08-05 10:22:28.000 NULL                     NULL   NULL
             User1      2015-08-06 19:29:02.000 2015-08-06 21:05:26.000  5784   1.606666
             User1      2015-08-18 11:54:42.000 2015-08-18 20:57:49.000 32587   9.051944
             User1      2015-08-19 12:10:48.000             NULL         NULL   NULL
             User1      2015-08-20 11:57:04.000 2015-08-20 20:57:19.000 32415   9.004166
             User1  2015-08-24 18:14:26.000                 NULL         NULL   NULL
             User1  2015-08-28 17:14:05.000                 NULL         NULL   NULL
             User1  2015-09-03 17:40:53.000                 NULL         NULL   NULL
             User1  2015-09-04 18:27:25.000                 NULL         NULL   NULL
             User1  2015-09-07 10:58:24.000 2015-09-07 17:55:52.000     25048   6.957777
             User1  2015-09-08 17:51:20.000                 NULL         NULL   NULL
```

Comment: Could you please amend this query according to MS SQL server as i am not able to understand the statements, also please share the results of the query.

Comment: I have edited my code according to MS SQL sever. let me know it it works

Comment: Sorry but the query is not working as i can see lot of NULL values which is incorrect as i am able to some data using my query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  FinalEntranceData.EmpName,FinalEntranceData.eventdatetime [LoginTime],FinalExitData.eventdatetime [LogoutTime],DATEDIFF(second,FinalEntranceData.eventdatetime,FinalExitData.eventdatetime) As Seconds FROM 
(
    SELECT  seqnumber,empName,eventdatetime FROM
    (
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empName,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),eventdatetime,112) ORDER BY eventdatetime)seqnumber,empname,eventdatetime FROM #TempData WHERE trnname ='Entrance'  
    ) EntranceData WHERE seqnumber=1
) FinalEntranceData
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  seqnumber,empName,eventdatetime  FROM 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empName,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),eventdatetime,112)  ORDER BY eventdatetime DESC  )seqnumber, * FROM #TempData WHERE trnname ='Exit'
    )ExitData  WHERE seqnumber=1

)FinalExitData ON FinalEntranceData.empname =FinalExitData.empname AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),FinalEntranceData.eventdatetime,112) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),FinalExitData.eventdatetime,112)
```

Comment: the query looks good however it is failing. Below is the results i am getting.
A 2015-08-05 10:22:28.000 2015-08-05 09:46:19.000 -2169
A 2015-08-25 17:35:25.000 2015-08-25 02:28:31.000 -54414
Time cannot be negative. The logout time should always be greater than login time.

Comment: record in database 2015-08-05 10:22:28 is login time and 2015-08-05 09:46:19. is exit time in particular day.so i think there is data problem.

Comment: No actually, instead of making a swipe IN, user did a OUT as first swipe for that day, and later did IN which is causing the problem. I am looking for a query which can handle such conditions and mark LoginTime as NULL for OUT and LogoutTime as NULL for IN.